# Are materials for printing from color negatives in darkroom still available in 2019?

Tags: darkroom

I wonder if the materials, paper and chemistry, are available even today in 2019?
I used to make color prints in the seventies and might do it again if someone still sell the required materials.
Jyrki, Mikkeli Finland

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  In the 1970s, you probably used the EP-2 chemistry system and paper.  This system was long ago replaced by the RA-4 system, which works fairly similarly but is incompatible.  You won't have to change your working methods much, if you remember what those methods were.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, it's a dying breed but it's still kickin'.

Some papers: https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/buy/Color/ci/801/N/4288586367

Some chemicals: https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/buy/For-Color-Paper/ci/596/N/4288586376

I'm not sure about the shipping to Finland or if these things exist in your local market...but for the time being, they *do* exist.

Answer (score 0):

Mind that, here at the beginning of 2019, one of the key manufacturers (Tetenal) of photographic chemicals is reported to be facing severe crisis. Future availability of materials might change due to that, so you might want to postpone any investment in darkroom gear and especially process-specific stuff until the dust has cleared.